# What does 'reason' mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage

The Enlightenment, by contrast, is about reason for everyman. 
The Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro.
what does **reason** mean in this context? Does it mean **reasoning** of **cause**?
What the sentence mean if it is **cause**?

[image: does]

Comment: [*European politics, philosophy, science and communications were radically reoriented during the course of the “long 18th century” (1685-1815) as part of a movement referred to by its participants as the **Age of Reason**, or simply the **Enlightenment**.*](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19690920-enlightenment---age-of-reason) So what you're really asking is *Why was the (Age of) Enlightenment also called the Age of Reason?* Which I personally think is Off Topic here.

Comment: @FF It is possible that you are inferring the real question being asked. But it certainly is not the question actually asked. The use of "reason" in the highlighted text is very odd and deserves explication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly literary style and must be interpreted figuratively. What is meant is

> It was a common thought among thinkers of the Enlightenment that all normal adults were capable of reason and therefore of finding truth

In other words

> reason for everyman

is meant as

> everyone has been granted the capacity to reason

in distinction to Plato's aristocratic prejudice. Reason is for the benefit of us all.

It is the kind of playful use of language that must be very obscure to those whose native language is not English.